# Early 90s (short-lived) medieval series with lots of swordplay

Tags: story-identification, medieval

Trying to identify / remember a television show from the early 90s, possibly very late 80s. It was on 'expanded cable' but not premium networks.

So the setting was medieval, lots of swords and armor and horses etc. Largely Caucasian cast with outrageous hair. Some point of importance was this primary location... a fort or keep or some kind. I could swear 'keep' or 'fort' was in the title. No magic or fantasy elements. Just humans and swords.

Basic production values, no memorable actors or scenes.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: Possibly - Roar (1997) with Heath Ledger - only 13 episodes, set in ancient Ireland with supposedly Roman overlords

Comment: @Dai I thought about this one too, but although he was still young back in '97, having famously won an Oscar posthumously later in life (a phrasing which doesn't make sense, but anyway), don't you think Heath Ledger would fall in the *memorable actors* category?

Comment: If there are no magic or fantasy elements, isn't it off-topic?

Comment: I thought of *Roar* too, but *Roar* contained fantasy elements - magic was real and the main villain (Longinus) was an immortal Roman soldier who had stabbed Jesus with his spear, 400-odd years ago, and was cursed to never die as a result.

Comment: Not really sure why this is "off topic" since it medieval and swords seem to be appropriate - I can't answer but this sounds like "Wizards and Warriors" (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085113/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_66) 1983

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it could be [Covington Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covington_Cross).

Basically a 14th century soap opera, it was a very short lived series on ABC in the states. The closest the show had to a big name was [Nigel Terry](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0856050/), known for playing King Arthur in John Boorman's *Excalibur*.

Comment: Ione Skye had at least one big movie before that.  And her dad is a famous singer.

Comment: It is *absolutely* Covington Cross. Oh wow. I've been going back in my brain trying to remember this for yeeeears. Thank you so much!